# How to see what DHCP client does?

Tags: linux, dhcp

- Does the dhcp client on Linux write any logs?
- If not, can logs be enabled and how?
- If it writes logs, where can they be found?
- How does a typical log of a dhcp client look like when obtaining IP and
  nameservers from a DHCP server?
- Where can I find the source code of the DHCP client?

In case there are relevant differences between Linuxes: I am interested in Debian 8.1 (default minimal installation amd64).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "the dhcp client on Linux". There are plenty of different dhcp clients for Linux and they all log different ways. There's probably a default one for Debian 8.1 though I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ISC's DHCP client is usually called `dhclient` in most Linux distributions. From `man dhclient`:

> The client normally prints no output during its startup sequence. It
>   can be made to emit verbose messages displaying the startup sequence
>   events until it has  acquired an address by supplying the -v command
>   line argument. In either case, the client logs messages using the
>   syslog(3) facility.

There are two possible ways to read your system log. On most systems that use systemd, you have to use `journalctl`, whereas `cat /var/log/syslog` is valid for systems that still employ a traditional init system.

Therefore, if your system is using systemd's logging facility, you can use `journalctl | grep -Ei 'dhcp'` to get DHCP client logs. Otherwise, enter `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -Ei 'dhcp'`.

Here is what my DHCP client log typically looks like:

```
Jul 20 14:17:39 trueclient1 NetworkManager[2622]: <info> (wlan1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3325
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 NetworkManager[2622]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 NetworkManager[2622]: <info> (wlan1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 dhclient: DHCPACK from 10.8.8.1
Jul 20 14:17:42 trueclient1 NetworkManager[2622]: <info> (wlan1): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
```

Comment: On Debian 8.1 journalctl works, on ubuntu-14.04.2-server the entries are in /var/log/syslog. Thanks. But: there are only very few entries, for example only the IP adress is logged, the DNS servers are not. Is it possible to configure more verbose output?

Answer (score 5):

A hacky (but effective) way to debug dhclient on many Linux platforms is to enable **bash tracing** in **/sbin/dhclient-script**.

dhclient runs that script on most OS variants I've checked (RedHat, Debian, etc).

Simply adding `-x` to the shebang (first line) in that script should enable tracing each line to console, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Then you can run, for example

```
dhclient -r #release lease
dhclient #re-acquire lease
```

And you should see lots of output, not only from dhclient-script, but from all the included `.d` scripts in /etc/dhcp*.

The trace output should allow you to figure out what's happening and what decisions the code is making (reference the script itself when looking at the output).

You can usually deduce the inputs (eg parameters including IP, GATEWAY, etc) the script received from this output, but if not, you can temporarily add something like this to the script just before the exit:

```
   env | logger -t dhclient-debugging
```

Then check your log after running dhclient (/var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231936/50978) to a similar question, `dhcpdump` is useful to view dhcp packets in a readable format:

`dhcpdump -i eth0`

Example dump with redacted values:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2023-12-29 04:44:26.672
    IP: 1.2.3.4 (00:00:00:00:00:00d) > 1.2.3.4 (00:00:00:00:00:009)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: dd99df6c
  SECS: 1
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 1.2.3.4
YIADDR: 1.2.3.4
SIADDR: 1.2.3.4
GIADDR: 1.2.3.4
CHADDR: 00:00:00:00:00:009:00:00:00:00:00:000:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         5 (DHCPACK)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         1.2.3.4
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      461 (7m41s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               1.2.3.4
OPTION:   6 (  8) DNS server                1.2.3.4,1.2.3.4
OPTION:  15 (  6) Domainname                .local
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         1.2.3.4
OPTION: 121 (  8) Classless Static Route    deadbeefdeadbeef ........
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   1.2.3.4
OPTION: 249 (  8) MSFT - Classless route    deadbeefdeadbeef ........
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -2):

Please find the answer inline.

- Does the dhcp client on Linux write any logs?

  Yes, it does.
- If not, can logs be enabled and how?

```
 1. Edit dhcpd.conf and add this line
  log-facility local7;

 2. Edit syslog.conf and append 
  local7.* /var/log/dhcpd.log
```

- If it writes logs, where can they be found?

  /var/log/dhcpd.log

- How does a typical log of a dhcp client look like when obtaining IP
  and nameservers from a DHCP server?

galaxy dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0d:62:d7:a0:12 via eth0

galaxy dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.5 to 00:0d:62:d7:a0:12 via eth0

galaxy dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.1) from 00:0d:62:d7:a0:12 via eth0

galaxy dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.5 to 00:0d:62:d7:a0:12 via eth0

- Where can I find the source code of the DHCP client?

  [Link 1](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/dhcp/4.3.2/dhcp-4.3.2.tar.gz)

  [Link 2](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/net/isc-dhcp)

Comment: The OP is talking about DHCP *client*. DHCPD is DHCP server daemon.

Comment: There seems to be no file named dhcpd.conf on my system. There is a file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf. There is no file syslog.conf, but a file /etc/rsyslog.conf. I made the configuration changes to those files, restarted rsyslog, shut down eth0, switched it on again. But no log file appears. I get some DHCP messages on the console. Even after a restart of the machine I get no log messages.