# Where can I find the DHCP client logs in centos

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp

I am running a PC with **centos** Linux. I have two ethernet ports. One configured as DHCP server and the other to use DHCP to obtain IP address(client). I am interested in getting the history of lease times I got and provided. Is there a log file with that data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see what DHCP client does?](http://superuser.com/questions/944687/how-to-see-what-dhcp-client-does)

Comment: I believe these logs are kept in your router. Log into your router, they should be logged there.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill the answer was for Ubuntu but it helped me to find the right way doing it on centos

Answer (score 4):

it is in /var/log/messages (thanks to David for mentioning [How to see what DHCP client does?](https://superuser.com/questions/944687/how-to-see-what-dhcp-client-does))
var/log/syslog in Ubuntu equivalent to var/log/messages in centos